# kube-dns and weave-net not starting

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi3, weave, kube-dns

I am deploying Kubernetes 1.4 on Ubuntu 16 on Raspberry Pi 3 following the instructions at http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/.  The master starts and the minion joins no problem but when I add weave kubedns won't start.  Here's the pods:

```
k8s@k8s-master:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-k8s-master                      1/1       Running             1          23h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-master            1/1       Running             3          23h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-master   1/1       Running             1          23h
kube-system   kube-discovery-1943570393-ci2m9      1/1       Running             1          23h
kube-system   kube-dns-4291873140-ia4y8            0/3       ContainerCreating   0          23h
kube-system   kube-proxy-arm-nfvvy                 1/1       Running             0          1h
kube-system   kube-proxy-arm-tcnta                 1/1       Running             1          23h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-master            1/1       Running             1          23h
kube-system   weave-net-4gqd1                      0/2       CrashLoopBackOff    54         1h
kube-system   weave-net-l758i                      0/2       CrashLoopBackOff    44         1h
```

The events log doesn't show anything.  getting logs for kube-dns doesn't get anything either.

What can I do to debug?

Comment: What does the "kubectl logs weave-net-4gqd1 weave" command show? In my case it was a failed DNS lookup (host not found). I haven't resolved this problem, but looks like a weave issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As Bryan pointed out, Flannel is not the only overlay network anymore.

Note this two hints in the [kubeadm install documentation:](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/)

<del>Flannel is the only network overlay support for arm</del>

> <del>If you are on another architecture than amd64, you should use the flannel overlay network as described in the multi-platform section</del>

When using Flannel, you need to make a kubectl init --por-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

> Note: this will autodetect the network interface to advertise the
>   master on as the interface with the default gateway. If you want to
>   use a different interface, specify
>   --api-advertise-addresses= argument to kubeadm init. **If you want to use flannel as the pod network, specify
>   --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 if you’re using the daemonset manifest below.** However, please note that this is not required for any
>   other networks besides Flannel.

You may also would like to check [my automated step-by-step installation for Raspberry Pi 3 with Ansible](https://www.sesispla.net/blog/language/en/2017/01/recipe-kubernetes-cluster-with-raspberry-pi-3/), since there is no issue with DNS and probably will work with Ubuntu 16 as well:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       busybox-894550917-7vj3z                        1/1       Running   0          15h
default       busybox-894550917-p9vnl                        1/1       Running   1          3d
default       gogs-3464422143-cf5wb                          1/1       Running   0          16h
kube-system   dummy-2501624643-pxmgz                         1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   etcd-master.cluster.local                      1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master.cluster.local            1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master.cluster.local   1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-discovery-1659614412-vrhv4                1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-dns-4211557627-kpsj4                      4/4       Running   8          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-d1bgg                          2/2       Running   6          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-fcp4b                          2/2       Running   6          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-n7p3m                          2/2       Running   6          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-tn7nd                          2/2       Running   6          3d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-vpk4w                          2/2       Running   6          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-5nmtn                               1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-gq7bz                               1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-lkkgm                               1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-mlh3v                               1/1       Running   1          3d
kube-system   kube-proxy-sg8n8                               1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master.cluster.local            1/1       Running   2          3d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-3507263287-h9q33          1/1       Running   2          3d
```

Comment: "Flannel is the only network overlay support for arm" is no longer true; see other answer

Comment: kubeadm docs has not officially updated to reflect the change you mention. This comment is specific if you are using kubeadm

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out; the docs were fixed on 24 Mar, but the change was overwritten.  Now fixed again.

Answer (score 4):

`kube-dns` won't start until the network is up.

Look in the `kubelet` logs on each machine for more information about the crash that is causing the CrashLoopBackoff.

<del>How did you get ARM images for Weave Net?  The `weaveworks/weave-kube` image on DockerHub is only built for x64.</del>

Edit: as @pidster says [Weave Net now supports ARM](https://www.weave.works/weave-net-1-9-released-encrypted-fast-datapath-arm/)

Comment: Weave Net now supports ARM: https://www.weave.works/weave-net-1-9-released-encrypted-fast-datapath-arm/